# How to know in repository if any file is checked out

Tags: svn, ant, hudson

I am trying to do our build process via Hudson, ant and we use SVN repository.

Before copying files to workspace in Hudson from SVN repository, I want to check, if anybody has not checked-in the files that they checkout.

If somebody checked out, I want to  stop the build process and send a message:

---

User1:  Currently checked out File1, File2.

User13: Currently checked out File9.

Aborting the build process. Please check-in all files and restart process.

---

Answer (score 1):

This information is not available in code that is checked-out. However, you can use [locks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.locking.html).

Comment: Can I get list of Locks on files. User A locked files 1,23. User B locked files 6.  Total 3 files locked.  Also for this, I have to ask users to lock files before modifying.

Comment: For a list of locks on objects in your repository, you can use [`svnadmin lslocks`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.lslocks.html). And yes, this solution relies on your users remembering to lock files.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're talking about the detection of [file locks in Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.locking.html). Far as I know this feature is not supported by Hudson/Jenkins